# how to host mobile application

Tags: node.js, flutter, hosting

I create mobile application project with flutter and NodeJS and SQL DB .
how can I host my mobile app and make it online for every one .
I mean I want  every one can access the API online (hosting)

Comment: I voted to close this question because the topic is too broad to cover in a few paragraphs here. There are hundreds of ways to host a web app.  A full answer would require many pages or even an entire book. Please [edit] your question to narrow the focus to the specific problem you encounter first. Once you have done that the question will be reviewed and reopened.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller if u don't want to answer just ignore the question and go out ,,,

Answer (score -1):

You need to [push your app (flutter) on an app store](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios), then host your backend (SQL DB, NodeJS server).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  They ask how to do the hosting and you just say "then host your backend"

Comment: thank you for your answer i got it know i know the first step that i should host the backend ,,,, thank you again .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).